# pre-evaluation in a definition of a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, evaluation

I am new to python and encounter a problem with a small piece of code aiming at implementing a menu with Qt:

```
def setChoice(self,choice=None):
  do something here...

listOfChoices=[choice1,choice2,choice3]

menu=QMenu(self)
  for choice in listOfChoices:
    action=menu.addAction(choice)
    action.triggered.connect(lambda : self.setChoice(choice=choice))
```

The problem is that the `setChoice()` function is always called with `choice=choice3`, the last choice of the for loop. How to solve this problem properly ?

And a probably related question about immediate partial evaluation:
How to save in memory `f= lambda x : x+1` from a piece of code like `a=1; f=lambda x: x+a` ?
Thanks for your explanations.

Denis

Answer (score 4):

This is a troublesome gotcha of Python `for` loops: the loop variable is created in the enclosing scope, and re-assigned for each iteration.

To get around this, you need to create a new local scope so that there is some place to "save" the variable:

```
for choice in listOfChoices:
    def act(choice):
        action=menu.addAction(choice)
        action.triggered.connect(lambda : self.setChoice(choice=choice))
    act(choice)
```

Or, in your second question,

```
def act(a):
    return lambda x: x + a
blah = act(1)
```